# How to translate query to doctrine2 query builder

Tags: doctrine-orm

How can I translate this query into doctrine2 query builder?

```
select c.name from company c join user_company uc on c.id=uc.company_id and user_id=136302
```

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have the similar problem